# Fixed sidebar that doesn't overlap with footer

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a sidebar that remains fixed at it's position when I scroll the page up/down. At the same time I want it stop scrolling when footer is reached so that the sidebar doesn't overlap with footer.

I used this plugin http://mojotech.github.com/stickymojo/
However, I am making some mistake in it's implementation. Can somebody please help me with this?

**Edit**

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper { width: 1000px }
#sidebar { float: left; width: 164px }
```

The footer is fetched from a file called footer.phtml I have added this in footer.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stickyMojo.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sidebar').stickyMojo({ footerID: '#footer', contentID: '#content' });
    });
</script>
```

The script stickyMojo.js shows up in the resources, but the sidebar doesn't stick to it's position.

Comment: My HTML structure is like this - 

<div class="wrapper">
   <div id="sidebar"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>

CSS -

.wrapper{width:1000px;}
#sidebar{float:left; width:164px;}

Comment: The footer is fetched from a file called footer.phtml
I have added this in footer.phtml
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stickyMojo.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sidebar').stickyMojo({footerID: '#footer', contentID: '#content'});
  });
</script>

The script stickyMojo.js shows up in the resources. But the sidebar doesn't stick to it's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I believe it's the fact that you don't have your `#footer` *inside* your  `#wrapper` that's causing the issue.

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYRf5/) that you can compare.

**Edit**

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYRf5/1/) with the footer outside the wrapper.

As for loading extra content as the user scrolls, the plugin seems to handle the 'stickyness' of the `#sidebar` automatically. Just make sure the loaded content affects the `height` of the `#main` div.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYRf5/3/) that demonstrates how to do it.

Comment: I am not allowed put the #footer inside #wrapper. Also, the #content div goes on loading some data as we scroll down.

Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a few more examples. Hope that helps. :{D